# The responsive menu (Sidr menu) is not working with anchors

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using the [responsive menus](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_menus), specifically the Sidr menu, the menu is not working when the paths have anchors.  When I do click in a item with anchor the menu is still opened.  The toogle in the menu is not working.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this question is here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2697767